# HL7 NHapi API OML_O21 PatientName object properties

Tags: hl7, nhapi

I am using `NHapi API` http://nhapi.codeplex.com/ for `HL7` in .net applcation. Request from audience to provide an example on how to set objects properties like PatientName and PatientAddress example in OML_021 object how we can set PatientAddress. I have tried through below line but it generate index out of range error actually HL7 XAD type array have 0 element .

```
o.PATIENT.PID.**GetPatientAddress()[0]**.StreetAddress.StreetName.Value =" Sample Address";
```

I do not see any function / property to set PatientAddress object which is actually of type actually HL7 XAD type array .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
PID.PID.GetPatientAddress(0).StreetAddress
```

The get methods will expand the collection if the existing collection is too small for the required index.